# In what cases do the buttons disappear in reviews?

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

The review in question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4862553).

> [image]

I just noticed it was because it was migrated... in that case, shouldn't this be cleared from the Close Queue?

Comment: Are we sure it's not an audit that just can't be completed because it removed all the buttons? FWIW, the buttons show up for me, as a moderator. I don't want to break it though.

Comment: @animuson My theory is that I don't have an account with closing privileges on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Looking into it more, this is definitely an audit. Don't know why it removed the buttons. Good luck passing that one!

Comment: The exact same review item came up a couple of minutes ago. It was a question from CodeReview and definitely an audit because it had the [tag:PHP] tag inserted. Also skipping it did not result in a failed audit.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Skipping never fails audits. I'm just curious to why a migrated question wasn't removed from the queue (or why a migrated question was placed as an audit in the first place).

Comment: Tired of this audit popping up and confusing people so I just completed it. Hopefully it doesn't get selected again.